# How would you say e.g. creativity isn't something that only belongs to graphic designers?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

Can't think of the word or phrase to use, can anyone help me?
Creativity isn't solely the domain of graphic designers? 
Something to do with prerogative?

Comment: You should add context. Where would you use this phrase?

Comment: Graphic designers are one type of artist. Creativity is a property that can attributed to any type of artist, and there are hundreds more.

Comment: @John, even that's a bit of a tight jacket. Literally anyone can be creative, whether a graphic designer, a more general artist, or just a human being.

Comment: Are you looking for "*Creativity isn't exclusively within the purview of graphic artists*"?

Comment: You almost have it right in your question: *Creativity isn't the sole prerogative of graphic designers*.

Comment: @DanBron: s/artist/person/g

Comment: I want to suggest "Graphic designers don't have a monopoly on creativity" but without knowing why and how you want to use this phrase, it's impossible to know if that's a good suggestion or not. Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 3):

*Graphic designers don't have a monopoly on creativity.*

I hear this most often with respect to *truth*: I'm told that Christians don't have a monopoly on truth, or something like that. It seems in that context to be effectively a claim to relativism.

(I've just noticed, after posting this, that the same phrase was suggested by someone above in a comment, but I'll leave it here since I came up with it independently, and since answers are, after all, supposed to be posted as answers.)

Answer (score 1):

"Creativity isn't solely the province of graphic designers".

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. Perhaps because the more idiomatic way to say it might be *"Creativity isn't the sole province of graphic designers."*

Comment: @JLG - I considered that (because, as you say, it's a formulation one often hears), but rejected it because it doesn't mean what the words supposedly say: literally, it means, 'creativity isn't the only area that graphic designers are involved in', which isn't the emphasis the OP wanted.